# Is it right to say "Viewpoints made easy"?

Tags: meaning

I'm not native in the English language and I'd like to know if when I say "Viewpoints made easy" your perception leads you to something like:

> Viewpoints made easy. An easy form to
>   connect and represent points of view
>   and understandings about the world
>   knowledge.

Comment: What do you mean by "viewpoints"? To me, it means a place (usually in the countryside) where there is a good view of the surrounding scenery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a native (American) English speaker, my perception is that when someone or something says "X made easy", X is normally considered to be a difficult and complicated item, program, or topic, which the speaker (or book, program, product, etc.) proposes to demystify and explain.

I would not ordinarily consider an individual's point of view to be inherently a difficult thing to comprehend.  (Some may certainly be more difficult than others, but as a general rule, "putting yourself in another's shoes" is not too tough.)

Judging by your example of what you want the sentence to mean, I am inclined to think that "Viewpoint relationships and mappings made easy" might be the better way to express your meaning, as your form sounds like it's designed to create charts and diagrams showing the connections between different points of view.

Answer (score 1):

"Viewpoints made easy"... that does really make sense.

Something "made easy" means something is presented in a simplified manner. For example, a book may have the name "Gardening Made Easy". It would presumably be a book for townsfolk who had never had a garden before and need some basics to get started.

I would rather say: "Viewpoints clarified"